# DataProc Avro Version Causing Error on Image v1.0.0

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

We are running a few dataproc jobs with [dataproc image 1.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/concepts/dataproc-versions) and [spark-redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift).

We have two clusters, here are some details:

- Cluster A -> Runs PySpark Streaming job, last created `2016. Jul 15. 11:27:12 AEST`
- Cluster B -> Runs PySpark Batch jobs, the cluster is created everytime the job is run and teardown afterwards.
- A & B runs the same code base, use the same init script, same node types etc.

---

Since sometime last Friday (`2016-08-05 AEST`), our code stopped working on cluster B with the following error, while cluster A is running without issues.

The following code can reproduce the issue on Cluster B (or any new cluster with image v1.0.0) while it runs **fine** on cluster A.

Sample PySpark Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext()
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([{'user_id': 'test'}])
df = rdd.toDF()

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "FOO")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "BAR")

df\
    .write\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://foo.ap-southeast-2.redshift.amazonaws.com/bar") \
    .option("dbtable", 'foo') \
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://bar") \
    .option("extracopyoptions", "TRUNCATECOLUMNS") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

The above code fails in both of the following situations on Cluster **B**, while running **fine** on A. note that the [RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html) is created via cluster init script.

- Running in interactive mode on master node:

  ```
  PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark \
      --verbose \
      --master "local[*]"\
      --jars /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar \
      --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:1.0.0
  ```
- Submit the job via `gcloud dataproc`

  ```
  gcloud --project foo \
     dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
     --cluster bar \
     --properties ^#^spark.jars.packages=com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:1.0.0#spark.jars=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar \
     foo.bar.py
  ```

---

The error it produces ([Trace](https://gist.github.com/PaulLiang1/b5129ecd21bdd03fef42dfde39fc7e85)):

```
2016-08-08 06:12:23 WARN  TaskSetManager:70 - Lost task 6.0 in stage 45.0 (TID 121275, foo.bar.internal): 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.createDatumWriter(Lorg/apache/avro/Schema;)Lorg/apache/avro/io/DatumWriter;
    at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.<init>(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:55)
    at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyOutputFormat$RecordWriterFactory.create(AvroKeyOutputFormat.java:79)
    at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(AvroKeyOutputFormat.java:105)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter.<init>(AvroOutputWriter.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(AvroOutputWriterFactory.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-08-08 06:12:24 ERROR YarnScheduler:74 - Lost executor 63 on kinesis-ma-sw-o7he.c.bupa-ma.internal: Container marked as failed: container_1470632577663_0003_01_000065 on host: kinesis-ma-sw-o7he.c.bupa-ma.internal. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1470632577663_0003_01_000065
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

SparkRedshift:1.0.0 requires [com.databricks.spark-avro:2.0.1](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/6262705be14aeb010cc9a004a7dd770e3c269566/project/SparkRedshiftBuild.scala#L78), which requires [org.apache.avro:1.7.6](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/4a0983c2c50db591f1cf130a24b8c4ccf74cc830/build.sbt#L32).

Upon checking the version of `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData` on Cluster A:

```
root@foo-bar-m:/home/foo# spark-shell \
>     --verbose \
>     --master "local[*]" \
>     --deploy-mode client \
>     --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:1.0.0 \
>     --jars "/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar"
```

It produces ([Trace](https://gist.github.com/PaulLiang1/a3998fb95300044acb9e74076b5ee3c6)):

```
scala> import org.apache.avro.generic._
import org.apache.avro.generic._

scala> val c = GenericData.get()
c: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData = org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData@496a514f

scala> c.getClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
res0: java.security.CodeSource = (file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/bigquery-connector-0.7.5-hadoop2.jar <no signer certificates>)
```

While running the same command on Cluster B:

```
scala> import org.apache.avro.generic._
import org.apache.avro.generic._

scala> val c = GenericData.get()
c: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData = org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData@72bec302

scala> c.getClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
res0: java.security.CodeSource = (file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/bigquery-connector-0.7.7-hadoop2.jar <no signer certificates>)
```

---

[Screenshot of Env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WQUq.jpg) on Cluster B. (Apologies for all the redactions).
We've tried method described on [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/129) and [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/91) without any success.

This is really frustrating as the DataProc updates the image content **without** bumping the release version as the complete opposite of immutable releases. Now our code is broke and there is no way we could roll back to the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble! It's certainly not intended for breaking changes to occur within an image version. Note that subminor versions are rolled out "under the hood" for non-breaking bug fixes and Dataproc-specific patches.

You can revert to using the 1.0.* version from before last week by simply specifying `--image-version 1.0.8` when deploying clusters from the command-line:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create --image-version 1.0.8
```

Edit: For additional clarification, we've investigated the Avro versions in question and verified that Avro version numbers actually did *not* change in any recent subminor Dataproc release. The core issue is that Hadoop itself has had a latent bug where Hadoop itself brings `avro-1.7.4` under `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/` and Spark uses `avro-1.7.7`. Coincidentally Google's bigquery connectory also uses `avro-1.7.7` but this turns out to be orthogonal to the known [Spark/Hadoop problem with 1.7.4 vs 1.7.7](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12527). The recent image update was deemed nonbreaking because versions in fact did not change, but classloading ordering changed in a nondeterministic way where Hadoop's bad avro version used to be hidden from the Spark job by pure luck, and is no longer accidentally hidden in the latest image.

Dataproc's `preview` image currently includes a fix to the avro version in the Hadoop layer which should make it into any future Dataproc 1.1 version when it comes out; you might want to consider trying the `preview` version to see if Spark 2.0 is a seamless transition.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, it's a lot clearer now. 
Both version 1.0.8 and preview has tested to be working fine. This question may be a bit out of context, regarding the class path load order issue, we've tried with `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` and `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` and they did not work. Just wonder if you have any insight on that? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had much chance to play around with `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst`; if I had to guess I'd suspect it works mostly for submitting uber-jars which bundle the precise dependencies directly, and I wouldn't be surprised if dependencies referenced in `--packages` don't benefit from the special classloader settings.